# querySelector не дает доступа к value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, input

Получаю данные из формы, делаю все по туториалу, однако при записи `form.querySelector('[name="nickname"]')` не дает доступа к .value

Видел похожий вопрос на Stackoverflow, однако такой вариант у меня не работает и это не является решением.

Примечательно, если в `form.querySelector()` в скобки не записать ничего, то выбор .value появляется.

По id пробовал, не получилось

**`form.html:`**

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.com" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**`form.js:`**

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');

const nickname = form.querySelector("[name='nickname']");
const email = form.querySelector("[name='email']");

const data = {
    name: nickname.value,
    email: email.value
};

console.log(data)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `[email='email']` тут нужно name, вместо перовго email. А вообще почему бы не искать по id внутри формы?

Comment: @OliverPatterson да, там name, это в спешке для сайта дописывал. По id пробовал, та же самая проблема.

Comment: Кхм.. А вас JS код так и выглядит? Ну то есть.. Весь код выполняется сразу? ИБо при выполнении скрипта в таком виде логично выдаст пустые значения ибо в полях пусто.

Comment: @OliverPatterson да, код так и выглядит, но на неполноту кода уже указали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, такая записать должна показывать `null`--  `form.querySelector("[email='email']")`.

Чтобы было значение в инпуте должны быть прописаны `value="12"`. А если нужно чтобы данные были данные при отправки форму нужно что-то такое.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {......})
```

**Например:**

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const nickname = form.querySelector("[name='nickname']");
  const email = form.querySelector("[name='email']");

  const data = {
    name: nickname.value,
    email: email.value,
  };

nickname.value = '';
    email.value = '';

  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" required><br>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.com" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Я такое видел в туториале, но не понял что оно делает и убрал его. Что должно быть в функции? (В туторе не описано)

Comment: НУ.. скорее ваш код начиная с `const data`

Comment: @Lcashe добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Мне кажется излишне добавлять поиск элементов внутри submit, лучше вынести за пределы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, согласен с вами. Это я для примера, чтобы автор вопроса понимал куда вставлять его код

Comment: @АлександрСычёв заработало, однако теперь при нажатии на кнопу Submit, поля не очищаются как было до этого. Но это наверное тема уже другого вопроса. Спасибо

Comment: @Lcashe, пожалуйста. Добавил в ответ - отчистка инпутов

Comment: @АлександрСычёв ну тут уже мог и сам догадаться в принципе. Спасибо